# Loop in variable php

Tags: php

```
$createquery=' "Select * from provaEngine where keyword like "%'.$int[$y] .'%" '.
    while(isset($lol[$var])){
        echo $lol[$var]
    }.' ';
```

How can I put all the `$lol` variable into the `$createquery` variable without using a loop?

Comment: Kind of hard to tell from what you have, did you look at `implode()`? Your sample script doesn't really have enough to go on.

Comment: Thank you , it works finally

Comment: Why do you have double quotes around the SQL inside single quotes?

Comment: I removed the double quotes some minutes ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `implode` function to generate a comma separated list as follows:

```
$createquery= "Select * from provaEngine where keyword IN (" . implode( ', ',  $lol) . ")";
```

Comment: There are quoting problems.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP `implode()`Function converts an Array into a String using a user-specified delimiter. In your Case, using `implode()` would be one way to avoid looping. The Snippet below demonstrates this:

```
<?php
    $createquery  = "Select * from provaEngine where keyword IN ("; 
    $createquery .=  implode(', ', $lol) . ")" ;
```